# Rayleigh–Jeans Law

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

In McQuarrie's *Quantum Chemistry*, the Rayleigh–Jeans law is given as:
$$\operatorname{d}\!\rho(\nu,T)=\rho_v(T)\operatorname{d}\!\nu=\frac{8\pi k_bT\nu^2\operatorname{d}\!\nu}{c^3}$$

where $\rho_v(T)\operatorname{d}\!\nu$ is the radiant energy density between $\nu$ and $\nu+\operatorname{d}\!\nu$.

1. Why does the author consider the range of the energy density, and why does he take the differential of the function $\rho(\nu,T)$?
2. Also, what is the difference between the two functions $\rho_v(T)$ and $\rho(\nu,T)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why would one be interested in knowing radiation between certain frequencies?

In this context, radiation is understand as a continuous function of wavelength or, equivalently, frequency.
At an *exact* frequency $\nu$, according to Rayleigh-Jeans law, [radiation is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law)

$$\frac{8\pi k_bT\nu^2}{c^3}\text{.}$$

In practice, it is hard to measure a *single* frequency.
We are thus interested in frequency intervals.
An exact frequency is the limit of a sequence of smaller and smaller intervals, so there is no problem here.

---

If we make the assumption that, for a sufficiently small interval, $\rho(\nu, T)$ doesn't vary, we get your definition for the differential $\operatorname{d}\!\rho(\nu,T)$:

$$\operatorname{d}\!\rho(\nu,T) = \frac{8\pi k_bT\nu^2}{c^3}\operatorname{d}\!\nu\text{.}$$

The assumption is fair due to the continuity of $\rho(\nu, T)$.
This is the approximation of an integral on a very small interval $\operatorname{d}\!\nu$ by the height of a point inside this interval ($\frac{8\pi k_bT\nu^2}{c^3}$) times its length ($\operatorname{d}\!\nu$).
No magic here.

---

So, if we *sum* an infinite amount of small intervals like the one above [we get an *integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral).
The total radiation between $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ will be:

$$\int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}\operatorname{d}\!\rho(\nu,T) = \int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}\rho(\nu, T)\operatorname{d}\!\nu = \int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}\frac{8\pi k_bT\nu^2}{c^3}\operatorname{d}\!\nu = 8 \pi k_b T \frac{v_2^3 - v_1^3}{3 c^3}\text{.}$$

Observe that $\rho(\nu, T)$ is quadratic in $\nu$.

---

> Also what is the difference between the two functions $$\rho_v(T)\text{ and }\rho(\nu,T)\text{?}$$

None.
Compare the definitions.
I changed the nomenclature because, in my opinion, there is no reason not to treat $\nu$ and $T$ on equal footing.